# How to run a script AND THEN save the output to a file?

Tags: python, powershell

I'm using Windows' Power Shell. I'd like to run a Python script that will take a long time to be finished (it's a code for data acquisition, so it'll take about a few hours to conclude). So, I'd like to be able to see all the prints and results on the terminal, but I would like to save all the output (in the end) as a string, a file or whatever.

I've been trying using the redirection commands like `python example_file.py > output.txt` ,  `python example_file.py | tee output.txt` and similars, but the problem is that those commands run all the script in the background and just show the results when it's finished (and, again, I'd like to be able to see the progress of the acquisition).

I've looked online and found that there's a command called "script" in Linux that serves for the same purpose that I want, but I've not found any equivalent for Windows Power Shell. I'm also accepting any solution in Python, it doesn't need to be necessarily on PS.

Please, someone help me?

EDIT: I'd like to see in real time the output. I mean, the intention is to see all the results of the code normally, as it's normally executed on the PS terminal, AND THEN save all the output to a file, to a string or whatever.

Example: if I run

```py
from time import sleep

print('banana')
sleep(3)
print('banana again')
```

it'll show, on the terminal, the first 'banana' and then, after three seconds, it'll show 'banana again'. The problem is that with the above codes it'll execute the script on the background and then show the results at once. And that's not what I want.

Comment: Use `Start-Process -wait`

Comment: You can also use `Start-Job`, and evaluate the status of the job/thread its running on.

Comment: `python example_file.py | tee output.txt` does not run in the background.  The issue you are experiencing is simply buffering.

Comment: @WilliamPursell , I'm not sure if I used the correct terms, but what I mean is that when I run the code with this command I don't see a "real time output". The result is shown on the shell at once and only when it's execution is finished. In a similar way, the `output.txt` file is filled at once and not "line by line".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use the following code:

```
from time import sleep

outputs = []

def myprint(print):
    global outputs
    print(print)
    outputs.append(print)


myprint('banana')
sleep(3)
myprint('banana again')
open("output.txt", "w").write("\n".join(outputs))
```

The code now writes into(and creates if not already there) a file named `output.txt` all the things printed with the `myprint()` function. If you want, you can also access them if  as single strings in the `outputs` array. Also, don't wonder, but in python you can use both `"` and `'` as the same thing.

Comment: Thanks a lot!! You know, I was looking for a way that I could do that as easy as running the `python example_file.py > output.txt` command. I've thought about doing something similar, but not the way you wrote. I mean, your idea is even more clever than what I was thinking. Again, thanks.